# grep searching groups

Tags: grep, regular-expression

I'm trying to learn to use grep groups, like sed \1\2\3, but have a problem. 
For example I filtering /etc/services file to separate all ports. What I do:

```
~$ grep -E '[0-9]{1,5}/(tcp|udp)' /etc/services
```

and now I get 'port/protocol'. Next, I try separate it with groups:

```
~$ grep -E '\([0-9]{1,5}\)/(tcp|udp)' /etc/services
```

and haven't any effect. Well, trying non extended grep:

```
~$ grep '\([0-9]*\)/[tcp\|udp]\1' /etc/services
```

but results not right (/t or /u). 
So, how to use groups?

Comment: *"...but results not right (/t or /u)"* What output do you want, exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are referring to regex back-references.

Please check these two references:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4609949/what-does-1-in-sed-do

http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/html_node/Back_002dreferences-and-Subexpressions.html

And see the output of `grep '\([0-9]\)\1' /etc/services` which will give you a resultset of lines where a digit is directly followed by the same digit (the back reference \1).

Comment: _\(...\) would capture the characters specified inside of the parens and \1 would be used to reference the first match, this is a part of regex._
and I think I trying do same